# Python raw dataclass to formatted dataclass transformation for avro schema

Tags: python, json

I receive some data from an api. I would like to define the raw responses schema and model it as a python dataclass, with the added benefit of using the `dataclasses_avroschema` package to programmaticly generate an avro schema. Further I would like to transform this raw response into a customizable second dataclass, also with an avro schema generation, based upon an optional parameter. The customizable bit needs to deal with nesting in the original raw response to make it easy to select nested items as well as be able to rename items.

I have come up with the following, with the essential piece being the `from_instance` class method:

```py
import dataclass_wizard
from dataclasses_avroschema import AvroModel
from dataclasses import dataclass
from operator import attrgetter

@dataclass
class Metadata(AvroModel):
    id: int
    acronym: str
    abbrev: str

@dataclass
class Glossary(AvroModel):
    title: str
    identifier: str
    metadata: Metadata


@dataclass
class FormattedGlossary(AvroModel):
    title: str
    metadata_id: int
    acronym: str
    glossary_abbrev: str
    id: int
        
        
    @classmethod
    def from_instance(cls, instance, mapper={}):
        return cls(**{
            k: attrgetter(v)(instance) 
            for k, v in mapper.items()
        })


data = {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "identifier": 300,
    "metadata": {
        "id": 100,
        "acronym": "SGML",
        "abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
    }
}
    
dc = dataclass_wizard.fromdict(Glossary, data)
print(dc)
# Glossary(title='example glossary', identifier='300', metadata=Metadata(id=100, acronym='SGML', abbrev='ISO 8879:1986'))
mapper = {
    "title": "title",
    "metadata_id": "metadata.id",
    "acronym": "metadata.acronym",
    "glossary_abbrev": "metadata.abbrev",
    "id": "identifier"
}
print(FormattedGlossary.from_instance(dc, mapper))
# FormattedGlossary(title='example glossary', metadata_id=100, acronym='SGML', glossary_abbrev='ISO 8879:1986', id='300')
```

It works, however I am unsure on the efficiency and if there are potential problems or other opportunities to improve this. Looking for any advice on if it can be improved further.

Additionally, sometimes a nested item can be None, I have not included that in this example here (and have not made the dataclass show that optionality) but was wondering if there would be a succinct way I can account for this in the `from_instance` method, besides a try except AttributeError.

Comment: You wrote `def from_instance( ... , mapper={}):`. Typically we frown on putting mutable containers in the signature, as a [pitfall](https://web.archive.org/web/20081024194213/http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) that future maintainers might fall into. Prefer to put `None` in the signature, and then assign `... = mapper or {}`. Why? Because the new `{}` dict is created at method invocation time, which is _long_ after when we parsed the method to generate bytecode. A dict which is created just once, at parse time, is very different from new dict on each invocation.

Comment: Understood, thanks J_H. one question for you, when you note `... = mapper or {}` what is the meaning of the ellipsis in this case? And likewise, should i instead just make `mapper` a positional arg instead as I think I do indeed want mapper to always be passed as a variable in the from_instance func.

Comment: I was trying to focus attention on the relevant part. The signature should default `mapper` to `None`. By "assignment" I meant: `mapper = mapper or {}`, as discussed in that Pitfall article. When you say "positional arg" I think you're talking about not giving it a default value, which is a different aspect of the signature. Yes, by all means, feel free to not mention a default in the signature. Me, personally? I kind of like defaults, it makes it easier to call an unfamiliar method. Whatever. You really _do_ want to understand the "mutable default" advice, so it won't trick you in future.